# RestSharp is missing Execute function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I am trying to use RestSharp (my first time). I am using their example:

```
var client = new RestClient( "http://example.com" );

var request = new RestRequest( "AddressJSON", Method.GET );
request.AddParameter( "name1", 123 );
request.AddParameter( "name2", 456 );
request.AddParameter( "username", "abc" );

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

However the function `client.Execute()` is missing from the library?!

I am using version 105.0.1.0 of the RestSharp from NUGET.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Phone version does not have the Execute function. You need to use ExecuteAsync instead.

e.g.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");

var request = new RestRequest("AddressJSON", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("name1", 123);
request.AddParameter("name2", 456);
request.AddParameter("username", "abc");

// execute the request
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    var content = response.Content; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with the line "var response = client.Execute(request);"
the error is the same... the version of the Nugget is 107.xx, and it only allows me 'ExecuteAsync', so I uninstalled the RestSharp Nugget and reinstalled it but in its version 106.0.x, where the problem disappeared, and Execute works perfectly!!

Comment: This is because all the synchronous calls have been removed in v107 as noted in the migration guide: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#making-requests